# SQL current date as column name

Tags: sql, db2, ibm-cloud

I let's say I have this simple statement:

```
Select sum(case ....'a little formlua here) as GETDATE() from table;
```

this will obviouslly not work... but what I need is for the column NAME to come up as the current date?

I'm doing this on db2

Comment: Try to do it with executing dynamic sql query.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is to create a column with some name and make the default value as the current date.

How can you have the column name as current date. In that case if you want so how many columns will be created daily

I think it's not the best practice to be followed so please try to avoid creating like this.

Instead, you can insert records with the current date by default.

Comment: Thank you but that is not the point. I am not trying to create a column in a table... just in a query. I need to column NAME to be current data and the values in that column will sum up values from my table where in another column the value is current date. The end result would be a QUERY (not a table) which has 15 columns ... 1st on would be ID and the next 14 would be "named" as the dates of last 14 days and they would sum up activity for those dates

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @sql nvarchar(128) = '
select 
C1 as [' + FORMAT(DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, GETUTCDATE())-0, 0), 'yyyy-MM') + ']
from #demo'
exec(@sql)
```

I was able to do something like this and it worked